# Matchit skips to next list item in HTML instead of closing tag

Tags: vim, tabs

I downloaded the Matchit plugin and used it on my HTML file. Everything worked as it was supposed to until I used it on my list.

```
<ol>
    <li id="link-1"><a href="http://www.reddit.com/">reddit</a></li>
    <li id="link-2"><a href="http://www.vim.org/">vim</a></li>
    <li id="link-3"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">w3schools</a></li>
</ol>
```

If the cursor is on the first `o` when I press tab the cursor jumps to the first list item instead of the closing `ol`. And when I'm on the `l` of the first list item the cursor jumps to the `l` of the next list item tag. But if I move the cursor over to the first a of the link tag and hit tab then Matchit works just fine and jumps to the closing tag. Matchit works for all tags but list items? How do I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starter, matchit is distributed with Vim without being activated. You don't need to download it, just follow the instructions at `:help matchit-install`.

Matchit uses a buffer variable called `b:match_words` to define pairs of matching tags: open an HTML file and type `echo b:match_words`. The value, here, is:

```
<:>,<\@<=[ou]l\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=li\>:<\@<=/[ou]l>,<\@<=dl\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=d[td]\>:<\@<=/dl>,<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>
```

If I understand `:help matchit` and these patterns correctly, the `<\@<=[ou]l\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=li\>:<\@<=/[ou]l>` part is where the "problem" is. Notice that the behaviour is the same for definition lists: instead of jumping to the end tag, matchit jumps to intermediary tags.

I'd guess that pasting this in an HTML ftplugin and doing a bit of customizing would solve the problem.

***edit***

This line seems to completely resolve the issue:

```
autocmd FileType html let b:match_words='<:>,<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
```

I've just removed the two totally unecessary pattern definitions for `<ul|ol>` and `<dl>`, leaving only the basic matches.

Comment: I wish there was an option “ignore everything but the first and last patterns in the list” for `%` (probably with leaving default behavior of `%` to `g%`). Or, at least, “swap `%` and `g%`”. You can’t really want to edit this for *every* ftplugin.

Comment: Do you know what I need to change the b:match_words variable to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay: I was on vacation. See my edit for a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `g%`. Matchit has bad behavior: instead of jumping to the closing tag it iterates on the list of related matches. I do not know whether it was coded for HTML, but while editing vimscript it will iterate `for`->`continue/break`->`endfor`. `g%` makes matchit iterate in the opposite direction, thus if you are on the first item it will bring you to the last (`for`->`endfor` in my example).

By the way, matchit was included in vim distribution some years ago. You don’t need to download it, I can’t even say whether it is updated anywhere but in vim distribution.