# Executing vim command based on filetype?

Tags: vim, command, file-type

I'm trying to have the command

```
    let b:match_words='<:>,<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
```

run every time I open an html file. I tried putting the line

```
    autocmd FileType html let b:match_words='<:>,<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
```

in a file named html.vim in both my ftdetect and ftplugin folders and nothing happened. How do I have the command run everytime I'mm in an html file?

The command is to change the matching behavior of matchit btw.

Comment: You could have posted a comment on [the answer to your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11852359/546861).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, your autocmd is alright; the problem is that you're trying to redefine the `b:match_words` definition done in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/html.vim`, so the execution order becomes important.

The place for these customizations is in the *after* directory, i.e. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`; just create a new file and put the `:let` command in there.

You can observe the sequence of sourced scripts via `:scriptnames`. In other cases, when you're not overriding default behavior, the `:autocmd FileType` is alright, but I prefer putting these (e.g. custom mappings) into `~/.vim/ftplugin/html_mymappings.vim`, as it provides better separation and helps keeping your `.vimrc` short and understandable.

The *ftdetect* subdirectory is for filetype detection, i.e. inspecting file path / name / contents to determine the correct filetype. It doesn't apply here, as the filetype is `html`.