# With vim what is the best way to select an xml block?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I would like to select the all `<div>`

```
     <div>
      ^cursor
        <p>
          currsor
          Issues reported by division from the
          <a href="https://re.fr"> https://re.fr</a>
            they will create an issue.
        </p>
      </div>
```

The best I found so far is:

```
V/div<Enter>n
```

or

```
Vjjjjjjj
```

but we have to count lines what is annoying.

I would like to use the fact that this is well formed XML so we know which tag close which tag.

PS: I have vim-surround-plugging installed

Comment: Activate and configure [`matchit` plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11852359/7976758) and use `%` to jump between open/close tags. To select ­— place cursor at the beginning tag and `V%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text objects are introduced in chapter 4 of the user manual and further listed under `:help text-objects`, where this is very easy to find:

```
at    "a tag block", select [count] tag blocks, from the
      [count]'th unmatched "<aaa>" backwards to the matching
      "</aaa>", including the "<aaa>" and "</aaa>".
      See |tag-blocks| about the details.
      When used in Visual mode it is made characterwise.
```